# lightning:recordForm not displaying full error message

Tags: lightning, lightning-record-form

I am getting only the below generic error message in `lightning:recordForm` component.

> An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.

[image]

But I see the below error in the `onerror` event parameter.

> "message":"An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.","detail":"","output":{"errors":[],"fieldErrors":{"Name":[{"constituentField":"LastName","duplicateRecordError":null,"errorCode":"REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING","field":"Name","fieldLabel":"Last Name","message":"Required fields are missing: [LastName]"}]}}

```
     <lightning:recordForm objectApiName="{!v.objectName}" aura:id="recordForm" 
                fields="{!v.fields}" 
                mode="readonly" columns = "{!v.columns}" recordId="{!v.recordId}" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"  oncancel="{!c.handleCancel}" onerror="{!c.handleError}">
                <lightning:messages />  
                </lightning:recordForm>
```

Comment: can you add markup?  also have you added ` <lightning:messages />` in your markup?

Comment: <lightning:recordForm objectApiName="{!v.objectName}" aura:id="recordForm" 
                fields="{!v.fields}" 
                mode="readonly" columns = "{!v.columns}" recordId="{!v.recordId}" onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}" onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"  oncancel="{!c.handleCancel}" onerror="{!c.handleError}">
                   <lightning:messages />  
                </lightning:recordForm>

Comment: Can you edit the question and then add markup?

Comment: The markup in your question doesn't seem to be the correct one. The `mode` in there is `readonly` where you cannot edit a record.

Comment: Jeyanth I have an edit button in the top right corner to change the mode from readonly to edit. Please see my screenshot in the original question.We did this to have only one edit icon instead of having multiple edit icons (in view mode) on each field.

Comment: What is the object here? And how is your required field defined? Any required field will always be marked with an * whenever the form loads.

Comment: i think your validation rules on field level, that field is not showing in this layout, BTW how did change the mode dynamically? may i know ?

Answer (score 1):

That seems to be the expected behavior for client-side validations using [`lightning:recordForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation). Referring to the *Client-Side Validation* section in documentation, it mentions the scenario you are experiencing (emphasis mine):

> **Client-Side Validation**
>
> The `lightning:recordForm` component performs client-side validation on record fields only if you interact with them. For example, **if you edit a record that includes a required field and submit the form without interacting with that required field, you see only that an error occurred. The form does not flag the required field as incorrect.**

Comment: Jayant I was interacting with the field (I blanked out the value in the required field)